# How to convert a , separated String to a table layout?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a field with values:

```
CM45024,CM45025,CM45026
```

I want to separate this into multiple items using subreport.  My jrxml source is:

```
<field name="docIdNoGRN" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[docIdNoGRN]]></fieldDescription>
</field>

<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement key="textField-53" x="311" y="1" width="88" height="15" uuid="2e040fd0-8fae-46e8-a845-fba421922992"/>
    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
    <font size="10"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{docIdNoGRN} != null && $F{docIdNoGRN}.toString().length() > 0) ? $F{docIdNoGRN} : " "]]>  
    </textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

The field can have 3 or more items as it depends on the data.  Instead of having one item in the report:

```
Item No.    Item ID.
   1        CM45024,CM45025,CM45026
```

I want to show it like this:

```
Item No.    Item ID.
   1        CM45024
   2        CM45025
   3        CM45026
```

Im using TIBCO Jaspersoft® Studio Professional - Visual Designer for JasperReport 6.1.1.

Comment: Yes, Not sure were to put this codes in the source and what I components I need to add.  Im very new to jrxml and only knows the basic stuff.  Are you online? Some of the issues I'm facing: 1. If I add the SubReport element I dont know how to configure it to point to $F{docIdNoGRN} 2.

Comment: When running, error I'm getting: [STDOUT] net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
  1. Field not found : _THIS

Comment: The sub report code I have already pasted in answer (you can copy and past), if your version of jasper report is 5.0 or above it will work (you only reference _THIS in subreport.

Comment: The <subreport> tag you put in your main report (detail band), be sure to point to the the your_subreport.jasper .jasper file (absoulte path), and that you have complied the your_subreport.jrxml, in my example I'm using a parameter to pass absolute path $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}, but you can also hard code it in subreportExpression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it can be achieved using subreport, assuming that your `$F{docIdNoGRN}` contains the String "CM45024,CM45025,CM45026"

1. Generate the data source that will be passed to the subreport

   ```
   <subreport>
    <reportElement x="163" y="15" width="200" height="100" uuid="9d6660e0-094e-4df3-9acb-74c031350b10"/>
    <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource(java.util.Arrays.asList($F{docIdNoGRN}.split(",")))]]></dataSourceExpression>
    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "your_subreport.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
   </subreport>
   ```

As you can see I `split(",")` your field `String` getting an `Array` that is converted to `List` and then passed in a `JRBeanCollectionDataSource`

2. Setup the subreport, the trick to reference our String is using **_THIS** as field value

example: (**your_subreport.jrxml**):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="jTest_subreport2" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="23d7765f-250f-4632-94c6-bbd218db3d11">
    <field name="_THIS" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="716bb440-2692-4c58-a1b7-972aff240c67"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="e5464783-d74a-4405-9997-ddb1531c6e42"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I have added the `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` to achieve the numbers (1,2,3) .

The output will be

> 1        CM45024
>    2        CM45025
>    3        CM45026

Note: You can also use the jr:table component to achieve this if you like to avoid generating a subreport (just define the table datasource as above)

Comment: It's a real necro, I know - but this is apparently the only easy-to-understand answer on this on the Internet. How would this work with a list and a table? I'm new to Jasper Reports and can't get it working.