# iterate an array in my jrxml file without using a datasource

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using jasperserver in my php/Symfony to generate my reports, and i pass parameters ad everything works fine. But now i want to pass an array containing the list of my user's name to jrxml file i really don't know if it's possible. i mean i know that we can do it with javabeans or creating a datasource, but in my case i mustn't use a database plus i use php.
So if anyone know how to pass the array and fetch it in the jrxml file to display all the values i would be so grateful 
so here is the code i'm want to use

```
$users = $em->getRepository('UserBundle:Utilisateur')->getAll();
$params = array(
            "montantEnLettre" => $montantEnLettre,
            "policeGroupeLibelle" => $contrat->getProduit()->getLibelle(),
            "montanttotal" => $contrat->getMontantTotale(), 
            "utilisateurs" => $users

        );

$d = new Client(
            "http://127.0.0.1:8080/jasperserver",
            "jasperadmin",
            "jasperadmin"
        );
$js = $d->jobService();
$d->setRequestTimeout(60);


$info = $d->serverInfo();
$report = $d->reportService()->runReport('/reports/epargne', 'pdf',null,null,$params);
```

I don't know if i can pass the users as a parameter and i have no idea how to fetch it my jrxml file

Comment: Check out if this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720591/how-to-convert-a-separated-string-to-a-table-layout, create a datasource from your parameter, use the datasource in a subreport or in a jr:table/jr:list component